# Excel : Change "Connection Only" back to query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, some other user changed my query. It went from **connection to an excel tab (parallel process shown below in pic)** [image: query that created a tab]

**to a "Connection Only", as shown below in picture:**
[image: Connection Only].

Power Query shows:

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Products, {"Product ID"}, Reviews, {"Product ID"}, "Reviews", JoinKind.Inner),
#"Expanded Reviews" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Reviews", {"Source.Name", "Retailer", "Product ID", "Product Name", "Product URL", "Total Reviews", "Total Responses", "Rejected Responses", "Reviews, 1 Star", "Responses, 1 Star", "Reviews, 2 Stars", "Responses, 2 Stars", "Reviews, 3 Stars", "Responses, 3 Stars", "Reviews, 4 Stars", "Responses, 4 Stars", "Reviews, 5 Stars", "Responses, 5 Stars"}, {"Reviews.Source.Name", "Reviews.Retailer", "Reviews.Product ID", "Reviews.Product Name", "Reviews.Product URL", "Reviews.Total Reviews", "Reviews.Total Responses", "Reviews.Rejected Responses", "Reviews.Reviews, 1 Star", "Reviews.Responses, 1 Star", "Reviews.Reviews, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 5 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 5 Stars"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Reviews",{"Brand", "Category", "Monitored Start Date", "Monitored End Date", "Engageable Start Date", "Engageable End Date", "Short Name", "Product Name", "Reviews.Product Name", "Attribute", "Reviews.Retailer", "Product ID", "Reviews.Source.Name", "Reviews.Product ID", "Reviews.Product URL", "Reviews.Total Reviews", "Reviews.Total Responses", "Reviews.Rejected Responses", "Reviews.Reviews, 1 Star", "Reviews.Responses, 1 Star", "Reviews.Reviews, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 5 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 5 Stars"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Reviews.Source.Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Reviews.Source.Name.1", "Reviews.Source.Name.2"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Reviews.Source.Name.1", Int64.Type}, {"Reviews.Source.Name.2", type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Reviews.Source.Name.2", "Category"}),
#"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Brand", "Monitored Start Date", "Monitored End Date", "Engageable Start Date", "Engageable End Date", "Reviews.Retailer", "Short Name", "Product Name", "Reviews.Product Name", "Attribute", "Product ID", "Reviews.Source.Name.1", "Reviews.Product ID", "Reviews.Product URL", "Reviews.Total Reviews", "Reviews.Total Responses", "Reviews.Rejected Responses", "Reviews.Reviews, 1 Star", "Reviews.Responses, 1 Star", "Reviews.Reviews, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 2 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 3 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 4 Stars", "Reviews.Reviews, 5 Stars", "Reviews.Responses, 5 Stars"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"Reviews.Retailer", "Site"}, {"Reviews.Source.Name.1", "YearMonthNum"}})
```

in
#"Renamed Columns"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

"View the query and connections window listing all the query names, right click the desired query name, choose the Load To option, then select table option"

Comment: You should accept you own answer then.